# Customize an email to have "Open this task" button without SP designer workflow

Tags: tasks, outlook, approval-process, outlook-add-in

We are using SP2016 on-premise. A scheduled PowerShell script is setup to send approval request email to approvers. The email contains the task link so that approver can click on it and approve his/her task.

Recently our company switched from other email program to Outlook (2013 desktop edition). I would like to make the "Open this task..." button show up in email. I tested create a simple designer workflow and work. However I do not want to build a designer workflow. May I know how to do it?